# Delphi Android Bluetooth_scan missing in Delphi 11.2

Tags: android, delphi, bluetooth, delphi-11-alexandria

I have upgrade to Delph 11.2 an android program that was working in 11.1 now comes up with bluetooth_scan permission missing. I think I should ask for android.permission.blue_tooth but this is not available in the androidapi.jni.os

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: I don't know anything about Android or Bluetooth, but I seriously suspect that `android.permission.blue_tooth` is wrong and should be `android.permission.bluetooth`.

Comment: What Android version? Android 12 requires additional permissions. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions